# enable_auto_commit=False, but still offsets are committed automatically

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

I'm using `kafka-python==2.0.2`, and have disabled `auto_commit` but still if I don't commit through code, offsets are automatically getting committed

In the below code even if I comment out `self.consumer.commit_async(callback= ....`, offsets are still getting committed

```py
class KafkaMessageConsumer:
    def __init__(self, bootstrap_servers: str, topic: str, group_id: str, offset_reset_strategy: str):
        self.bootstrap_servers: str = bootstrap_servers
        self.topic: str = topic
        self.group_id: str = group_id
        self.consumer: KafkaConsumer = KafkaConsumer(topic, bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers, group_id=group_id,
                                                     enable_auto_commit=False, auto_offset_reset=offset_reset_strategy)

    def consume_messages(self, consumer_poll_timeout: int, max_poll_records: int,
                         message_handler: MessageHandlerImpl = MessageHandlerImpl()):
        try:
            while True:
                try:
                    msg_pack = self.consumer.poll(timeout_ms=consumer_poll_timeout, max_records=max_poll_records)
                    if bool(msg_pack):
                        for topic_partition, messages in msg_pack.items():
                            message_handler.process_messages(messages)

                        self.consumer.commit_async(callback=(lambda offsets, response: log.error(
                            f"Error while committing offset in async due to: {response}", exc_info=True) if isinstance(
                            response, Exception) else log.debug(f"Successfully committed offsets: {offsets}")))
                except Exception as e:
                    log.error(f"Error while consuming/processing message due to: {e}", exc_info=True)

        finally:
            log.error("Something went wrong, closing consumer...........")
            self.consumer.close()
```

Is this a proper way to disable auto commit and commit manually?

Comment: What are you using to check offsets are committed?

Comment: I'm expecting, if I don't commit offset manually then in the next iteration call to `poll()` should return same record, but it is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`poll()` always moves forward, regardless of committing. It just does not **write offsets back to Kafka**.

If you *restart your app*, **then** would it pickup the same data again and again.